# Простой скрипт отправки формы на e mail

Tags: php

Здравствуйте! Вот самый простой способ отправки сообщения на email. В панели разработчика показывает "Status 200", но сообщение на почту не приходит. Есть ли решение проблемы?

```
<?php
//если была нажата кнопка Send
if($_REQUEST['ButtonSend']) {
 //если был использован метод POST
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {
  if((isset($_POST['text']) && $_POST['text']!="")) {
   //почта получателя
   $to = 'abc@list.ru'; 
   //загаловок сообщения
   $subject = 'сообщение'; 
   //сообщение в виде текста
   $message = $_POST['text'];
   //кодировка сообщения для текста
   $headers = "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8 \r\n";
   //отправка письма
   mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
  }
 }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title>New Страница</title>
</head>
<body>
 <form id="form" action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="text" required="required" placeholder="Text"/>
  <br />
  <br />
  <input type="submit" name="ButtonSend" value="Send"/>
 </form>

 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>

 <script>
  $(document).ready(function () {

  });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**===Это продолжение моего вопроса===**

Возможно я что-то упустил или не понимаю. Вот [здесь](https://www.epochta.ru/help/mailer/09_smtp.htm) показаны настройки. Я выбрал **mail.ru**  Это настоящая почта (специально создал) и настоящие настройки. 
Почта: **abc.123456789.abc@mail.ru**
Пароль: **abc12345ZZZ756**

Настройки

> SMTP-сервер: smtp.mail.ru (smtp.list.ru / smtp.bk.ru / smtp.inbox.ru):
>   2525 или 465 Аутентификация: ESMTP – RFC 2554 Шифрование: SSL Логин/
>   пароль:  имя почтового ящика полностью (name@mail.ru), ваш пароль к
>   почтовому ящику Email отправителя = логин Подключений к серверу
>   (потоков) –  1 Лимит: 1 сообщение/мин. или 200 email сообщений/день
>   POP3-сервер: pop.mail.ru (pop.list.ru / pop.bk.ru / pop.inbox.ru):110

А все сообщения, которые будут пользователь вводить из формы, должны например поступать на почту **zolinger@ukr.net**

Вот новый файл index.php, для удобства я все разместил в нем. Можете скопировать себе на сервер и попробовать выполнить. Укажите только свой email вместо **zolinger@ukr.net** что бы видеть, пришло сообщение или нет.

```
<?php
//FILE PHPMailerAutoload.php

/**
* PHPMailer SPL autoloader.
* PHP Version 5
* @package PHPMailer
* @link https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/ The PHPMailer GitHub project
* @author Marcus Bointon (Synchro/coolbru) <phpmailer@synchromedia.co.uk>
* @author Jim Jagielski (jimjag) <jimjag@gmail.com>
* @author Andy Prevost (codeworxtech) <codeworxtech@users.sourceforge.net>
* @author Brent R. Matzelle (original founder)
* @copyright 2012 - 2014 Marcus Bointon
* @copyright 2010 - 2012 Jim Jagielski
* @copyright 2004 - 2009 Andy Prevost
* @license http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/lesser.html GNU Lesser General Public License
* @note This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful - WITHOUT
* ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or
* FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
*/

/**
* PHPMailer SPL autoloader.
* @param string $classname The name of the class to load
*/
function PHPMailerAutoload($classname) {
 //Can't use __DIR__ as it's only in PHP 5.3 +
 $filename = dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'class.'.strtolower($classname).'.php';
 if(is_readable($filename)) {
  require $filename;
 }
}

if(version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.1.2', '>=')) {
 //SPL autoloading was introduced in PHP 5.1.2
 if(version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.0', '>=')) {
  spl_autoload_register('PHPMailerAutoload', true, true);
 }
 else {
  spl_autoload_register('PHPMailerAutoload');
 }
}
else {
 /**
 * Fall back to traditional autoload for old PHP versions
 * @param string $classname The name of the class to load
 */
 function __autoload($classname) {
  PHPMailerAutoload($classname);
 }
}
?>


<?php
//если была нажата кнопка Send
if($_REQUEST['ButtonSend']) {
 //если был использован метод POST
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {
  if((isset($_POST['text']) && $_POST['text']!="")) {
   //почта получателя
   $to = 'zolinger@ukr.net'; 
   //загаловок сообщения
   $subject = 'Заказать звонок'; 
   //сообщение в виде текста
   $message = $_POST['text'];
   //кодировка сообщения для текста
   $headers = "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8 \r\n";

   //require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

   $mail = new PHPMailer;

   //$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Раскоментируйте для отладки

   $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
   $mail->Host = 'smtp.mail.ru';                         // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
   $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
   $mail->Username = 'abc.123456789.abc@mail.ru';        // SMTP username
   $mail->Password = 'abc12345ZZZ756';                   // SMTP password
   $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
   $mail->Port = 465;                                    // TCP port to connect to

   $mail->setFrom('abc.123456789.abc@mail.ru', 'Mailer'); // От какого адреса отправляем письмо
   $mail->addAddress($to);                               // Получатель сообщения

   $mail->Subject = $subject;
   $mail->Body = $message;

   if(!$mail->send()) {
    die('Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo);
   }

  }
 }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title>New Страница</title>
</head>
<body>
 <form id="form" action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="text" required="required" placeholder="Text"/>
  <br />
  <br />
  <input type="submit" name="ButtonSend" value="Send"/>
 </form>

 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>

 <script>
  $(document).ready(function () {

  });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: //почта получателя $to = 'abc@list.ru' указана верно? она рабочая?
Php на сайте работает? Какой хостинг\сервер, не локальный (дэнвер)?

Comment: Ваш сервер отправку почты поддерживает? Заглушка на функцию mail не поставлена админами? Тело письма соответствует условию из описания функции http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mail.php ? Заголовки письма в UTF-8 должны быть кодированы: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mail.php#108669 Ну и в спам посмотрите ;)

Comment: используйти библиотеки для отправки эмэйл сообщений, валидные данные фром . ту и т.д. и посмотрите лог отправки можен не в пхп проблема.

Comment: На хостинге мне ответили "  только по stmp
, почты нет на фрихостинге" Что такое stmp ?

Comment: @Anton это означает, что отправить почту, через стандартный метод `mail()` - Вы не можете. Необходимо использовать внешний smtp(почтовый) сервер - для отправки почты. Например gmail. Все почтовые сервисы предоставляют возможность удаленной отправки почты через свой аккаунт, но в таком случае все письма будут исходить от Вашего личного почтового ящика или зарегистрируйте почту для Вашего сайта, например - `mysite@gmail.com`.

Comment: Спасибо Вам Konstantin Mitjurin за информацию. Я пытаюсь сделать форму "Заказать звонок". Нужно, что бы сообщения приходили на e-mail заказчика.

Answer (score 3):

Если у Вас бесплатный хостинг или Ваш хостинг не поддерживает e-mail рассылки, то для отправки сообщения на e-mail, Вам нужно воспользоваться сторонним smtp сервером.

**SendMailSmtpClass.php**

```
<?php
/**
* SendMailSmtpClass
* 
* Класс для отправки писем через SMTP с авторизацией
* Может работать через SSL протокол
* Тестировалось на почтовых серверах yandex.ru, mail.ru и gmail.com
* 
* @author Ipatov Evgeniy <admin@ipatov-soft.ru>
* @version 1.0
*/
class SendMailSmtpClass {

    /**
    * 
    * @var string $smtp_username - логин
    * @var string $smtp_password - пароль
    * @var string $smtp_host - хост
    * @var string $smtp_from - от кого
    * @var integer $smtp_port - порт
    * @var string $smtp_charset - кодировка
    *
    */   
    public $smtp_username;
    public $smtp_password;
    public $smtp_host;
    public $smtp_from;
    public $smtp_port;
    public $smtp_charset;

    public function __construct($smtp_username, $smtp_password, $smtp_host, $smtp_from, $smtp_port = 25, $smtp_charset = "utf-8") {
        $this->smtp_username = $smtp_username;
        $this->smtp_password = $smtp_password;
        $this->smtp_host = $smtp_host;
        $this->smtp_from = $smtp_from;
        $this->smtp_port = $smtp_port;
        $this->smtp_charset = $smtp_charset;
    }

    /**
    * Отправка письма
    * 
    * @param string $mailTo - получатель письма
    * @param string $subject - тема письма
    * @param string $message - тело письма
    * @param string $headers - заголовки письма
    *
    * @return bool|string В случаи отправки вернет true, иначе текст ошибки    *
    */
    function send($mailTo, $subject, $message, $headers) {
        $contentMail = "Date: " . date("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " UT\r\n";
        $contentMail .= 'Subject: =?' . $this->smtp_charset . '?B?'  . base64_encode($subject) . "=?=\r\n";
        $contentMail .= $headers . "\r\n";
        $contentMail .= $message . "\r\n";

        try {
            if(!$socket = @fsockopen($this->smtp_host, $this->smtp_port, $errorNumber, $errorDescription, 30)){
                throw new Exception($errorNumber.".".$errorDescription);
            }
            if (!$this->_parseServer($socket, "220")){
                throw new Exception('Connection error');
            }

            $server_name = $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];
            fputs($socket, "HELO $server_name\r\n");
            if (!$this->_parseServer($socket, "250")) {
                fclose($socket);
                throw new Exception('Error of command sending: HELO');
            }

            fputs($socket, "AUTH LOGIN\r\n");
            if (!$this->_parseServer($socket, "334")) {
                fclose($socket);
                throw new Exception('Autorization error');
            }



            fputs($socket, base64_encode($this->smtp_username) . "\r\n");
            if (!$this->_parseServer($socket, "334")) {
                fclose($socket);
                throw new Exception('Autorization error');
            }

            fputs($socket, base64_encode($this->smtp_password) . "\r\n");
            if (!$this->_parseServer($socket, "235")) {
                fclose($socket);
                throw new Exception('Autorization error');
            }

            fputs($socket, "MAIL FROM: <".$this->smtp_username.">\r\n");
            if (!$this->_parseServer($socket, "250")) {
                fclose($socket);
                throw new Exception('Error of command sending: MAIL FROM');
            }

            $mailTo = ltrim($mailTo, '<');
            $mailTo = rtrim($mailTo, '>');
            fputs($socket, "RCPT TO: <" . $mailTo . ">\r\n");     
            if (!$this->_parseServer($socket, "250")) {
                fclose($socket);
                throw new Exception('Error of command sending: RCPT TO');
            }

            fputs($socket, "DATA\r\n");     
            if (!$this->_parseServer($socket, "354")) {
                fclose($socket);
                throw new Exception('Error of command sending: DATA');
            }

            fputs($socket, $contentMail."\r\n.\r\n");
            if (!$this->_parseServer($socket, "250")) {
                fclose($socket);
                throw new Exception("E-mail didn't sent");
            }

            fputs($socket, "QUIT\r\n");
            fclose($socket);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return  $e->getMessage();
        }
        return true;
    }

    private function _parseServer($socket, $response) {
        while (@substr($responseServer, 3, 1) != ' ') {
            if (!($responseServer = fgets($socket, 256))) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        if (!(substr($responseServer, 0, 3) == $response)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;

    }
}
?>
```

> ===ЧТО НУЖНО СДЕЛАТЬ В ФАЙЛЕ index.php===
>
> Сюда вставьте Ваш email, с которого будут отправляться сообщения, лучше всего пользоваться mail.ru

//почтовый ящик, с которого будут отправляться сообщения
    $smtp_username = 'abc@mail.ru';

> Сюда вставьте пароль от этого почтового ящика

```
//пароль этого почтового ящика
$smtp_password = '12345';
```

> Правильно подберите сервер отправки почты

```
//сервер отправки почты
/*
gmail.com - ssl://smtp.gmail.com

mail.ru - ssl://smtp.mail.ru
list.ru - ssl://smtp.list.ru
bk.ru - ssl://smtp.bk.ru
inbox.ru - ssl://smtp.inbox.ru
*/
$smtp_host = 'ssl://smtp.mail.ru';
```

> Сюда вставьте email, на который будут приходить сообщения

```
//почта получателя
$to = 'abc@ukr.net';
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
//подключаем файл
require_once('SendMailSmtpClass.php');
?>

<?php
/*
желательно, что бы почтовый ящик был размещен на одном из почтовых серверов
yandex.ru или mail.ru или gmail.com
*/
//почтовый ящик, с которого будут отправляться сообщения
$smtp_username = 'abc@mail.ru';

//пароль этого почтового ящика
$smtp_password = '12345';

//сервер отправки почты
/*
gmail.com - ssl://smtp.gmail.com

mail.ru - ssl://smtp.mail.ru
list.ru - ssl://smtp.list.ru
bk.ru - ssl://smtp.bk.ru
inbox.ru - ssl://smtp.inbox.ru
*/
$smtp_host = 'ssl://smtp.mail.ru';

//Ваше имя или название Вашего сайта или организации
//в сообщении, в поле "от кого" будет эта информация
$smtp_from = 'Письмо от Антона';

//порт
$smtp_port = 465;

$mailSMTP = new SendMailSmtpClass($smtp_username, $smtp_password, $smtp_host, $smtp_from, $smtp_port);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title>New Страница</title>
</head>
<body>
 <form id="form" action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="text" required="required" placeholder="Text"/>
  <br />
  <br />
  <input type="submit" name="ButtonSend" value="Send"/>
 </form>

<?php
//если была нажата кнопка Send
if($_REQUEST['ButtonSend']) {
 //если был использован метод POST
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {
  if((isset($_POST['text']) && $_POST['text']!="")) {
   //почта получателя
   $to = 'abc@ukr.net'; 
   //загаловок сообщения
   $subject = 'загаловок сообщения'; 
   //сообщение в виде текста
   $message = $_POST['text'];
   //кодировка сообщения для текста
   $headers = "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8 \r\n";
   //отправка письма
   $result = $mailSMTP->send($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
  }
  if($result === true) {
   echo '<h1>Письмо успешно отправлено!</h1>';
  }
  else {
   echo '<h1>Ошибка отправления: ' . $result . '</h1>';
  }
 }
}
?>

 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <script>
  $(document).ready(function () {

  });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

!!!ТЕПЕРЬ ВСЕ РАБОТАЕТ!!! ВСЕМ СПАСИБО!!! МОЖЕТЕ СКОПИРОВАТЬ ЭТИ ДВА ФАЙЛА, ПОДСТАВИТЬ СВОИ ЗНАЧЕНИЯ И ПРОТЕСТИРОВАТЬ

Answer (score 0):

Для отправки писем в вашем случае необходимо использовать, например, [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)
Замените настройки на те, что даст вам почтовик.

```
<?php
//если была нажата кнопка Send
if($_REQUEST['ButtonSend']) {
 //если был использован метод POST
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {
  if((isset($_POST['text']) && $_POST['text']!="")) {
   //почта получателя
   $to = 'abc@list.ru'; 
   //загаловок сообщения
   $subject = 'сообщение'; 
   //сообщение в виде текста
   $message = $_POST['text'];
   //кодировка сообщения для текста
   $headers = "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8 \r\n";

   require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

   $mail = new PHPMailer;

   //$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Раскоментируйте для отладки
   $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
   $mail->Host = 'smtp1.example.com;smtp2.example.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
   $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
   $mail->Username = 'user@example.com';                 // SMTP username
   $mail->Password = 'secret';                           // SMTP password
   $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
   $mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

   $mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'Mailer');         // От какого адреса отправляем письмо
   $mail->addAddress($to);                               // Получатель сообщения

   $mail->Subject = $subject;
   $mail->Body    = $message;

   if(!$mail->send()) {

     die('Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo);
   }
  }
 }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title>New Страница</title>
</head>
<body>
 <form id="form" action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="text" required="required" placeholder="Text"/>
  <br />
  <br />
  <input type="submit" name="ButtonSend" value="Send"/>
 </form>

 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>

 <script>
  $(document).ready(function () {

  });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Уважаемый ilyaplot, посмотрите код и прочтите описание. Я сделал  изменения в вопросе.

Comment: @Anton ознакомился и не понял, существует ли проблема и какая.