# Вопрос по отправке html-писем

Tags: html, email

Здравствуйте. Я в html-письмах на уровне... нуля, примерно. Никогда ими не занимался. А тут поставили задачу - сделать так, чтобы менеджер с админки мог одним кликом их посылать. Т.е. сделать шаблон, по клику на "отправить" вставлять туда данные из формы и отправлять на известный электронный адрес

Всё бы ничего, но я довольно плохо понимаю, как вообще работает эта система. Ну, напишу я [вот так](https://habrahabr.ru/sandbox/93363/)... а что придёт получателю? Html файл или развёрнутое письмо? И что будет в этом конкретном случае с отображением картинок? В рунете я увидел мало информации и в основном она старая.

Буду очень признателен за совет :)

Comment: Так написали бы и отправили себе на почту, а если появились проблемы, тогда бы и спрашивали. А то получается вы даже не попробовали, а спрашиваете )

Comment: Это ведь займёт достаточно много времени) И я действительно плохо понимаю, как работает весь механизм отправления, что именно отправит POST, ... Поэтому хотелось не изобретать старый велосипед, а спросить разъяснений, или, быть может, ссылочку на них. Хотя я действительно мало нашёл именно по отправлению. Зато все учат, как сверстать)

Comment: [Можете глянуть сюда](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/542084/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%BD%D0%B0-e-mail)

Answer (score 0):

Я тебя прекрасно понимаю это болезненный вопрос для новичка и сам я был в подобном ступоре. Отвечаю:

в теге form должны быть атрибуты action="" и method="post" - это о том как отдавать данные

в принимающем php скрипте чтобы поймать данные, отправленные из формы используй глобальную переменную $_POST, только в полях формы не забудь про поля name=""
а чтобы отправить данные кому угодно используй функцию mail() - обо всем на что я обратил внимание - ты можешь найти в справочниках, если есть пробелы.
Иными словами - если необходимо просто отправить себе письмо используй функцию mail(). Если необходимо вывести на экран то что ввел в форму используй $_POST в принимающей форме. Если по отдельности загвоздка, то не переходи к слиянию, пока не разберешься в каждом из этих моментов.

в дальнейшем mail(); лучше не использовать, а переходить к smtp клиенту - поскольку google gmail уже не принимает письма, отправленные функцией mail();